# How to get address range of a process stack in MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, function, stack-memory

I'm debugging a program that has many `alloca` and triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS (with `-msanitize=address`) or crashes `__chkstk_darwin` (without compiler sanitizer). I want to know the valid stack address range which would let me know if the code is really exhausting or overflowing the stack.

Is there anyway to get it, either in `lldb` or from some external system info?